# SQL Server Compact & ClickOnce & Mutliple Users

Tags: clickonce, sql-server-ce

I am creating a clickonce app and planning on using SQL Compact. However, multiple users will be using the app on the same machine. Is this going to be possible for them to share the same database. If not, should I be using Express instead?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually about copying the database file somewhere everyone can get to it from their own account. ClickOnce apps don't run with any privileges, so I don't think they would be able to access the database if it was, say, in c:\ourdatabase.

If I were you, I would deploy the app to localhost on my machine, and copy the database to where I would want it to be. The app should point to that location. Log in as userA and run it and see if it can access the database successfully. Same for userB.

Now, if that works, you can try adding code to copy the database to that folder the very first time the application is run on that machine. Just check for the folder and the file in the folder, and if not there, copy it over there. Again, you'll have to try this out and see if it will work.

Comment: If I put SQL server compact database on a network share and this share is available for my Windows account, should it be available from ClickOnce app also?